nginx/docker - failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream
I am trying to deploy a dockerized Laravel application via Portainer. I want the website to be accessible via port 8080
This is my docker-compose.yml file:
version: '3.8'

services:
  laravel:
    restart: unless-stopped
    container_name: athena-app
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        - USER_ID=1000
        - GROUP_ID=1000
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
      APP_NAME: ${APP_NAME}
      APP_ENV: ${APP_ENV}
      APP_DEBUG: ${APP_DEBUG}
      APP_KEY: ${APP_KEY}
      APP_URL: ${APP_URL}
      DB_CONNECTION: mysql
      DB_HOST: database
      DB_PORT: 3306
      DB_DATABASE: ${DB_DATABASE}
      DB_USERNAME: ${DB_USERNAME}
      DB_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    expose:
      - "8080"
    depends_on:
      - database

  database:
    restart: unless-stopped
    image: mariadb:lts-jammy
    volumes:
      - v-database:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MARIADB_DATABASE: ${DB_DATABASE}
      MARIADB_USER: ${DB_USERNAME}
      MARIADB_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
      MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}

volumes:
  v-database:

Further, I have this Dockerfile:
############################################
# Base Image
############################################

# Learn more about the Server Side Up PHP Docker Images at:
# https://serversideup.net/open-source/docker-php/
FROM serversideup/php:8.3-fpm-nginx-alpine AS base

# Switch to root before installing our PHP extensions
USER root
RUN install-php-extensions bcmath gd

############################################
# Development Image
############################################
FROM base AS development

# We can pass USER_ID and GROUP_ID as build arguments
# to ensure the www-data user has the same UID and GID
# as the user running Docker.
ARG USER_ID
ARG GROUP_ID

# Switch to root so we can set the user ID and group ID
USER root
RUN docker-php-serversideup-set-id www-data $USER_ID:$GROUP_ID  && \
    docker-php-serversideup-set-file-permissions --owner $USER_ID:$GROUP_ID --service nginx
    
# Install the intl extension with root permissions
RUN install-php-extensions intl


# Switch back to the unprivileged www-data user
USER www-data

############################################
# CI image
############################################
FROM base AS ci

# Sometimes CI images need to run as root
# so we set the ROOT user and configure
# the PHP-FPM pool to run as www-data
USER root
RUN echo "user = www-data" >> /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/docker-php-serversideup-pool.conf && \
    echo "group = www-data" >> /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/docker-php-serversideup-pool.conf

############################################
# Production Image
############################################
FROM base AS deploy
COPY --chown=www-data:www-data . /var/www/html
USER www-data

Now, when I try to access my website via port 8080, I get this following error in the browser:
502 Bad Gateway
nginx

Checking the nginx error log gives me the following:
[error] 11#11: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 10.45.5.184, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1"

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here?
